# Unknown code on my website comments

Tags: php, html

During the last few weeks, I often find on my website these "Comment":

```
{"name":"BryantFlogy","email":"cgorillamail@gmail.com","message":"Hi, 
htmlkurss.xyz \r\n \r\nI&#39;ve been visiting your website a few times 
and decided to give you some positive feedback because I find it very       
Well done. \r\n \r\nI was wondering if you as someone with experience of 
creating a useful website could help me out with my new site by givingsome 
feedback about what I could improve? \r\n \r\nYou can find my site by 
searching for &#34;casino gorilla&#34; in Google (it&#39;s the gorilla 
themed online casino comparison). \r\n \r\nI would appreciate if you could 
check it out quickly and tell me what you think. \r\n\r\ncasinogorilla.com 
\r\n \r\nThank you for help and I wish you a great week!",
"datetime":"04\/28\/2019 01:44:49 pm"}
```

I have [this](http://htmlkurss.xyz/index.php) Website (under construction) and people can write comments [here](http://htmlkurss.xyz/contact.php).

Then I have two files, my **PHP file** where I have my code for HTML Form-Element, and the PHP class constructor, and I have a **.txt file**, where the comments are written.

Can anyone explain what does it does?

Comment: Nothing. Looks like spam. The better question to ask is how it appeared on your website? Can you provide more details?

Comment: seems like a genuine comment with no malicious parameters.

Comment: What "code" are you talking about? Nothing seems strange here.

Comment: Are you talking about `\r\n \r\n` and `&#34;`?

Comment: yes , about it , and 5 Days bevor more.. , all comment here https://i.imgur.com/K5MfdB8.png

Comment: `\r\n` and `&#34;` are not code. That's text encoding. Googling those things will tell you exactly what they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are dumping the POST array into a text file when an individual comments.

When inspecting the DOM, I can see you make use of post.

```
<form method="POST">
        <label for="name"><b>Name * </b></label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" value="">
        <label for="email"><b>E-mail * </b></label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="Email" value="">
```

So I'm guessing in the back-end your php code looks like this:

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $_POST;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

What you can do to get rid of the "code" is obtain the individual elements, such as this example:

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Commenter Name: " . $_POST["Name"] . "\r\n";
$txt .= "Email: " . $_POST["Email"] . "\r\n--\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

This will allow you to obtain the original string values without the formatting or array notation. Above Example:

```
Commenter Name: Jhon Doe 
Email: Joe@blow.com
-- 
Commenter Name: Jane Doe 
Email: test@example.com
-- 
etc
```

This should make things a lot cleaner and easier to read, I recommend storing comments in a table or mailing to yourself using the php mail(); function.

Comment: @567hz This should help: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: thanks for you comment ! , can you please give me a address where explain it.. , i am new with php... i know on html build table with <table> and <tr> but together with the function mail() , i do not know....

Comment: @567hz For the mail function, you will need to setup a mail server. Use Dovecot, postfix, and make a local mail user. Here is a tutorial: https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: thanks , i will does it on my localhost , but what to does on my web host ...

Comment: For your hosted server you will need to make MX records in your DNS for it to work, sorry I did not mention this: https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/mx (set servername to your servers IP to loopback, leave subdomain empty, and have priority at the default or 5)

Comment: Veryyyyyyyy Thanks for you help ! , what you think, that i to need a mail server when i only will administrate my comment ?

Comment: This would allow you to email comments or your website to your personal email. That way you can view your fans on-the-go with a mobile mail app!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93017/discussion-between-567hz-and-devsushi).